# unable to build thingsboard project properly

Tags: maven-3, thingsboard

"Failed to execute goal on project application: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.thingsboard:application:jar:1.3.1: Could not find artifact org.thingsboard:ui:jar:1.3.1 in jenkins (http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases)"
Getting error at the time of mvn clean install -DskipTests

Answer (score 0):

You should execute build command from a root project directory and not from the application directory.